# Are there differences in meaning or formality in the various readings of 家中?

Tags: readings

In this example sentence,

[時計]{とけい}がないので[家中]{かちゅう}を捜{さが}した。
I searched all over the house for the missing watch.

Jim Breen's WWWJDIC (and Jisho, and tangorin.com) list
家中 【うちじゅう; かちゅう(家中); いえじゅう】 whole family; all (members of) the family; all over the house

The suggestion [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%AE%B6%E4%B8%AD/#je-5520) seems to suggest that it 家中 is read うちじゅう

Do these various readings have different meanings or registers?

Comment: You can include _furigana_ using {}: see my edit.

Comment: Where did you find the sentence 「時計がないので家中を捜した。」 in which 「家中」 is read 「かちゅう」?

Comment: If one goes to https://j-talk.com/convert, the reading given is かちゅう

Answer (score 4, accepted):

家中{うち/いえじゅう} has two meanings. One is "an entire house", the other is "all people living in a house".

家中{かちゅう} has three meanings. One is "the inside of a house", another is "all people living in the house", and the other is "generic name of vassals of a feudal lord in Edo period".

However 家中{かちゅう} is rarely used in present days as the meanings of "the inside of a house", "all people living in the house"

Source: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/%E5%AE%B6%E4%B8%AD/m0u/